# Estimator of a normal mean: practical recommendation?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, multivariate-normal-distribution, steins-phenomenon

I have a sample of $n=370$ $5$-dimensional observations which can be reasonably well modeled using a multivariate normal distribution. I want to estimate the mean using this sample, which will be part of a report, and I came across the [Stein's paradox](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rjs57/SteinParadox.pdf). Given that the James-Stein estimator is biased and the sample mean is unbiased, I am unsure on whether I should report the Sample Mean or the James-Stein estimator of the mean (or both?).

What is the practical recommendation in this case?